# How to correctly get rid of human poop?

Tags: environmental-impact, lifestyle, family

I want to live alone in a floor above where I'm currently living cause I don't stand my family, only inconvenience, there is nothing not even tiles, I don't mind the discomfort but, how can I get rid of my poop, can I burn it or what do I do with it? (I plan on investing on a solar panel for the electricity, and an electric stove for cooking).

I live in Colombia and I plan to invest on a 100Watt panel with inverter, battery and charger controller (only things I use are my cellphone and laptop for college, ilumination and electric stove), while I save to install the aqueduct I need a way of disposing of my waste (poop) with as less impact to the environment as possible. I would only use my income for me and my cat's food and water, the roof has a big space for the panel and for putting small crops.

This is a very long term thing, I want to do everything for my self, and try to save every penny to put the space in good condition, live and even later lease the space when it is in better conditions. My income is 800.000 COP or around 220 dollars monthly.

Comment: I'm not sure how regulations are in Columbia, but where I live all houses and apartments are required to be connected to the sewer system. The only other option is to get a special permit and install an alternative waste system but that is also bound to specific regulations. Any idea if there are such regulations in Columbia? If not perhaps that's a question to ask on law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make a composting toilet out of very simple parts, and those can work very well. But you need a supply of sawdust, woodchips or some other dry organic material. My brief experiment with dried grass was not successful although I've read that it can work. There are lots of places on the web where people document their experiments:

The problem you will have is disposing of the compost. It really needs to be stored in a warm place for months then buried in a garden. But if you have access outside space with a garden that's one option.

[https://www.lowimpact.org/the-simplest-diy-compost-toilet/#:~:text=A%2020%20litre%20bucket%20sits,the%20sawdust%20and%20that's%20it](https://www.lowimpact.org/the-simplest-diy-compost-toilet/#:%7E:text=A%2020%20litre%20bucket%20sits,the%20sawdust%20and%20that%27s%20it).
https://goodlifepermaculture.com.au/wheelie-bin-compost-toilet/

Answer (score 0):

There were projects in India working on far-reaching technological solutions to the need for community toilets. Basically, I said that there is a well-known logistical solution and it is septic tanks:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septic_tank

I went on to say that the community toilet buildings could be themed with stainless-steel roofs that funnel rainwater into stainless-steel tanks such that the rainwater is used to flush the toilets. Of course the stainless-steel tanks could also have outdoor faucets for drinking water.

Now one county, that I am familiar-with in the U.S., requires building lots to be one acre in size to use a septic tank. Also, the ground has to pass percolation tests to qualify for septic tank use. But don't forget the drain-field which leads to the next item.

A large project such as a city or county could use wetland areas to process treated waste water instead of just discharging into a river. Here are links to an internationally renowned project:

http://sewaneewetlands.org/case-study-the-clayton-county-constructed-wetlands

http://www.gwri.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/files/docs/2005/ThomasMike%20paper%20April%2013.pdf

https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=90043021

https://www.wwdmag.com/ccwa-completes-phase-i-huie-constructed-wetlands-project

https://www.accesswater.org/publications/-287961/design-and-construction-of-treatment-wetlands-on-a-sloping-site

https://www.accesswater.org/?fileid=-30106

https://www.georgiatrend.com/2008/12/01/water-solutions/

I listed a large number of links because I was looking for something like several miles of flow through rocky creeks before reaching large slow moving wetlands. What I found was that the waste-treatment plant pumps to a 55 acre constructed wetlands of successive ponds that eventually flow into a reservoir. Of course the constructed wetlands do grow-up with natural vegetation. Also, there is surrounding acreage.

http://sewaneewetlands.org/constructed-wetlands

But here is the original link that includes constructed wetlands for small projects:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_wetland#:~:text=A%20constructed%20wetland%20(CW)%20is,areas%20lost%20to%20land%20development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_wetland#:%7E:text=A%20constructed%20wetland%20(CW)%20is,areas%20lost%20to%20land%20development)

Now I am looking for information on a city park project that sends sewer-line overflow into a rocky creek.